# Edit Windows protected systemfiles in VMWARE?

Tags: windows

How can I edit Windows protected system internal files in VMWARE?
On a normal PC, I can simply reboot the PC and use a different Operating System to prevent the 'access denied' error... But how do I edit those protected files when inside VMWARE?

Comment: "In VMware" mean inside the guest or what? It's pretty unclear what you are asking although the existing answer assumes a particular scenario.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily map or mount VMWare virtual disk to the host system and access needed files. To quote [VMWare Workstation 9 Documentation Center](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-896E61F5-0865-4D3B-975E-DE476AFC7168.html):

> When you map a virtual disk and its associated volume to a drive on the host system, you can connect to the virtual disk without opening a virtual machine.
>   After you map the virtual disk to a drive on the host system, you cannot power on any virtual machine that uses the disk until you disconnect the disk from the host system.

The menu is accessed by:

- Windows host: Select File > Map Virtual Disks.
- Linux host: Select File > Mount Virtual Disks.

Comment: @User88004: Within VMware Workstation Menu. What VMWare product are you using?

Comment: For some reason VMware does not allow me to read+write on those mounted virtual disks.

Comment: Before you do that, make sure your virtual machine is in shut down state, not suspended.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use another operating system, for example boot from a Linux LiveCD and make the changes you want. VMware allows you to use an ISO file directly for the dvd drive, you can do that by going in the hardware settings of your VM, selecting the CD/DVD drive and then selecting the ISO image. Your VM should then boot on the Livecd and you can now do your changes as you normally would.

Comment: How do you do that inside VMWARE?

Comment: edited my answer with a bit more details